# Is there a way to do a lookup on a formatted json column in SharePoint?

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatting, relational-database, lookup

I have 3 SharePoint Lists:

1. Application
2. Interface
3. Dataflow

The '**Interface**' List:

- Fields: [*Interface_Title*], [*Input*], [*Output*]

The [*Input*] and [*Output*] are lookup columns to an '**Application**' List; both lookups to the [*Application_Title*] field. Therefore:

> '**Application**'.[*Application_Title*] = '**Interface**'.[*Input*]

> '**Application**'.[*Application_Title*] = '**Interface**'.[*Output*]

*Example: Application table contains: Excel, Power BI, PowerApps, etc... So an Input could be Power BI and output PowerApps.*

[*Interface_Title*] from the '**Interface**' list has column formatting that contains json code that concatenates the input and output: (The reason being, you cannot create a calculated column with lookup columns)

```
>     {   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
> "elmType": "div",   "txtContent": "= [$Input.lookupValue] + ' to ' +
> [$Output.lookupValue]" }
```

*Example: Therefore the [Interface_Title], would contain 'Power BI to PowerApps'* (Concatenates: [Input Value] + to + [Output Value]

The 3rd list, '**Dataflows**' contains an *[Interface]* field that is a lookup to [*Interface_Title*]. Therefore:

> '**Interface**'.[*Interface_Title*] = '**Dataflow**'.[*Interface*]

The problem I am running into, is the lookup field [*Interface*] in the '**Dataflow**' List does not give me all the options from the '**Interface**' list, so I am unable to add what interface is used for a specific dataflow and I believe it has something to do with the json code.

Is there something I need to add to the code to fix this? or any other workaround?
(I'd prefer not to have to use Power Automate if possible)